# Tesseract-OCR / Pillow not working with Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-tesseract

I have installed Tesseract-OCR using the provided installer and added it to the path. I have also installed Pillow using pip through CMD. But when I attempt to import them into pycharm it says that the modules do not exist.

When I type 'tesseract' in CMD, it outputs the correct information, so I think I must be missing a step somewhere.

I am attempting to import them using the Following:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
```

Please help...

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: I am, yes. I set up the environment I am using through Pycharm when making the new project.

Comment: Did you install pytesseract as well using pip in your virtualenv?

Comment: I installed it using the installer from the website, not through the terminal in the venv. When I attempt to install it in the terminal now I am getting an error. I am guessing I shouldn't have used the installer?

Comment: Try to follow this link: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/ Remember that tesseract and pytesseract are two diferent things. I don't know the OS that you are using but in Linux I installed the tesseract in the system and the pytesseract in my virtualenv.